# Firestore: Accessing more composite custom indexes with a simpler query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

On Firebase Firestore, if the client tries to access more composite custom index with a simpler query, would it work?

For example, let's say there's a collection and I set a custom composite index of its fields like this: `field1` Ascending / `field2` Ascending / `field3` Descending

On the client, trying to get a document `.where("field1", isEqualTo: smth).where("field2", isEqualTo: smth).where("field3", isEqualTo: smth)` would work, but what if there's one less `.where()` like this: `.where("field1", isEqualTo: smth).where("field2", isEqualTo: smth)`

Would the second query (which doesn't query `field3`) still work even if the more composite index (which indexes 3 fields) is set? Or would I have to add a new custom index that only indexes those two fields?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Firestore needs an index for every query you perform. However, there are situations in which it doesn't necessarily require one. If you're querying Firestore using multiple equality clauses and an orderBy, then it can re-use existing indexes. So it can merge the indexes for simple equality filters to build the composite indexes needed for larger equality queries.

So let's take your example. If you perform the following query without ordering:

```
db.collection("someCollection").where("field1", isEqualTo: smth)
                               .where("field2", isEqualTo: smth)
                               .where("field3", isEqualTo: smth)
```

There is no need for an index at all, as it is created automatically. If you, however, add an orderBy:

```
db.collection("someCollection").where("field1", isEqualTo: smth)
                               .where("field2", isEqualTo: smth)
                               .where("field3", isEqualTo: smth)
                               .orderBy("someField")
```

Then indeed an index is required. That's the most common case in which Firestore can reuse indexes. So if for example, you create the following indexes:

| Collection | Fields indexed | Query scope |
| --- | --- | --- |
| someCollection | ↑ field1 ↑ someField | Collection |
| someCollection | ↑ field2 ↑ someField | Collection |
| someCollection | ↑ field3 ↑ someField | Collection |

This means that the above query will work perfectly fine, but the below queries will also work:

```
db.collection("someCollection").where("field1", isEqualTo: smth)
                               .orderBy("someField")
```

And:

```
db.collection("someCollection").where("field1", isEqualTo: smth)
                               .where("field2", isEqualTo: smth)
                               .orderBy("someField")
```

See the absence of `.where("field3", isEqualTo: smth)`? The same rules apply if you need a descending order.

Comment: Oh thank you for your detailed explanation. Can I expect the same behavior even if I combine those three composite indexes (↑ field1 ↑ someField / ↑ field2 ↑ someField / ↑ field3 ↑ someField) into single, but more composite index (↑ field1 ↑ field2 ↑ field3 ↑ someField)?

Comment: No, you cannot expect the same behavior. It's exactly the opposite. You can combine those composite indexes, but it doesn't mean that it will work for singular queries. You have to create those singular indexes in order to satisfy larger equality queries.

Comment: Hey Shawn. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Nope I'm good. Thanks