# Should I index all fields inside a collection ? Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, indexing

I want some help with the Composite indexing.

I have some queries about different fields on the collection of **tickets**.

Should I create many composite based on conditions of each query  (as row 1, 3, 4 in the picture) 
Or I should create only one composite indexing all fields in the tickets collection  (as row 2 in the picture)

Which one is the best option ? I appreciate you help.

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't you just create the ones you need to satisfy the queries required by your app?  Anything else is a waste of space - indexes cost money to store, whether or not you use them.

Comment: OMG, is that you for real? @Doug . I am a big fan of your tutorial. Thank you for sharing your knowledge to the community.
Back to the question, I know that Indexing everything will cost more because of more storage usage. However, I am confusing Whether I should combine all fields that I need to index (from all queries) into only one composite (as row 2 in the picture) Or split them separately based on each query conditions (as row 1, 3, 4 ...) 
I really want to listen to your opinion.

Comment: Have you tried it both ways?  Does it work for your app's required queries in either case?

Comment: Ok, I see the point now, 
I have tried to remove all other composites but keep the one that indexing all fields of the collection. It does not work for other queries of different fields combinations. 
Thank you for leading me through my issue. Highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74022144/firestore-accessing-more-composite-custom-indexes-with-a-simpler-query) will also help.

Answer (score 0):

Answering as Community wiki, As mentioned by Doug stevenson in above comments.

Combining all fields that need to index (from all queries) into only one composite that satisfies the queries required by your app. Indexing everything will cost more because of more storage usage, whether you use them or not.

As suggested by Alex Mamo you can refer to this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74022144/firestore-accessing-more-composite-custom-indexes-with-a-simpler-query) which may help you.